# Input box and text vanish on backspace/delete in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In IE10 with IE8 browser mode, the input box and text vanish when the backspace or delete key are pressed while the input has focus.  Moving the mouse makes everything reappear as normal.  Without the call to `getBoundingClientRect()`, it works fine.  What's going on?

Here is [this markup](http://jsbin.com/EMuHAzU/4/edit):

HTML:

```
<input id='input'>
```

Javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.attachEvent("onpropertychange", function(event) {
    if (event.propertyName === "value") {
        input.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, sounds like getBoundingClientRect is forcing a reflow, but the browser forgets to repaint.

Comment: @Teemu I took out the `type='text'` to get a minimal example, but that doesn't affect the result here.  I assume that since the input has focus, the IE shortcut for `history.back()` isn't applied.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes, I agree.  How can I trigger a repaint manually?

Comment: Oh, it is, at least with IE10, I'm getting back to the page where I started, when pressing `backspace`. Maybe it has something to do with JSBin.

Comment: Its been mentioned elsewhere that [IE10 compatibility mode handles onpropertychange wrong](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/ie10-compatibility-mode-handles-onpropertychange-wrong/). Dunno if that's the case but FWIW it works for me in IE8 vanilla.

Comment: @Moob That's really hilarious.  Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: To force a repaint, you can try changing some visual property of the element, e.g. `input.style.width = input.style.width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been mentioned elsewhere that [IE10 compatibility mode handles onpropertychange wrong](http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/ie10-compatibility-mode-handles-onpropertychange-wrong/). Dunno if that's the case but FWIW it works for me in IE8 vanilla.